# jquery ui menu: is it possible to use several as drop down and flyout instances of a css top bar nav?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

Beginner. I am not sure if the title question is worded correctly, but I will try to explain what I looking for. I would like to create a very basic top bar navigation, and use jquery ui menu for each selection drop down/fly out. So I think this would be very possible and relatively simple to do, but I am wondering, how would you go about positioning each menu instance under the top bar if its based on percentages
?
I am new to a lot of this so I am not really sure if its a jquery or a css question? I greatly appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would go about it. Hope this helps and let me know if you need anything else.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Nav Item 1</a>
            <ul class="subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
        <a href="#">Nav Item 2</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nav Item 3</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".subnav").menu().hide();

    $("#menu>li").each(function(index, el){

        $(el).hover(function(){
            $(this).closest('li')
                .find('ul')
                .show()
                .animate({"opacity":1}, 250);
        },function(){
             $(this).closest('li')
                 .find('ul')
                 .animate({"opacity":0}, 250, function() {
                 $(this).hide();   
                 });
        });
    });
});
```

​
CSS:

```
ul{ 
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding-right:1em;
overflow:hidden;
}

#menu>li{ 
    float:left; 
    background-color:whiteSmoke;
    width:30%;
}

.ui-menu{
    width:100%;
} /*100% since its nav item will be relative*/

#menu>li>ul{opacity:0}
​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/EQPVf/15/

Comment: @Dom...wow thanks! I am learning all this but was having the trouble connecting the dots. This really helps me a lot! greatly appreciated!

Comment: @dom...is there a way to use the .find for the nearest element  as you have done above,  but only for the next descendant, and not any children of that element? asking because as I use the above it seems that any nested flyouts appear while hovering the grandparent css selection...thanks!

Comment: nm...i should have tried before asking, but that was really easy... > for the selector just before ul...works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way I do it for jQuery UI version 1.9.1. Top to bottom.

INCLUDES:

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-latest-version.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
#menu li { display:inline-block; width: auto; }
#menu li.sub { display:block; width: auto;}
```

jQuery:

```
// Menu
$(function() {
  $( "#menu" ).menu({
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var num = ui.item.index();
      switch(num) {
    case 0:
      Option1(); // dummy function to handle selection
      break;
    case 1:
      Option1Sub(); // make your own function to handle
          break;
        case 2:
          Option2(); // dummy function to handle selection
          break;
    case 3:
      BlaBla(); // make your own function to handle
      break;
      }
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu" class="ui-menu">
  <li><a href="#" title="Option 1..."><b>Option 1</b></a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#" title="Option 1 sub..."><b>Option 1 sub</b></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Option 2..."><b>Option 2</b></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Bla Bla..."><b>Bla Bla</b></a></li>
</ul>
```

[itsSOezy](http://itssoezy.com/).com .. jQuery makes it easy.